# Upgrade from gcc 5.4 to gcc 6.3 std::thread std:ref issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, sfml, stdthread, gcc6

I recently upgraded to gcc 6.3 from gcc 5.4. C++ code that used to compile and run just fine stopped compiling and I'm not experienced enough to deduce what is going wrong.

The code is in an object that I created to spawn windows using sfml. It instantiates a thread that uses an sfml::Window pointer to update the image based on an externally set pointer to a video frame.

The code is basic and simple and I'm spawning threads elsewhere in the code (although not threads of an object).

Here are code snippets:

```
class owindow
{
public:
  ...
private:
  ...
  std::thread renderThread;
  ...
  void windowRender(void);
  ...
};

owindow::owindow(std::string name, win_t type, int width, int height, uint32_t *image)
: renderThread()
{
  typ = type;
  wid = width;
  hei = height;
  nam = name;
  frame = image;
  resizewin = false;
  killthread = false;

  ...
  window = new sf::Window(sf::VideoMode(windowwidth, windowheight), name.c_str(), sf::Style::Default, settings);
  window->setVerticalSyncEnabled(false);
  ...

void owindow::start(void)
{
    // Start the render thread.
  renderThread = std::thread(&owindow::windowRender, this);
}
```

The errors are generated on the renderThread = line shown above (line 174, in error output) are long and brutal and honestly I feel like I'm drowning when I try to understand them. Since when does c++ have tuples? LOL. I'm learning python at work and finally got what a tuple is and then I have this happen...

I just checked, it still compiles and runs with gcc 5.4.

Here are the errors, note this is just the first few errors, I didn't want to spam the forum.

Updated:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/tuple: In instantiation of 'static constexpr bool std::_TC<<anonymous>, _Elements>::_MoveConstructibleTuple() [with _UElements = {const std::tuple<void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>&}; bool <anonymous> = true; _Elements = {void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*}]':
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/tuple:626:248:   required by substitution of 'template<class ... _UElements, typename std::enable_if<(((std::_TC<(sizeof... (_UElements) == 1), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_NotSameTuple<_UElements ...>() && std::_TC<(1ul == sizeof... (_UElements)), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_MoveConstructibleTuple<_UElements ...>()) && std::_TC<(1ul == sizeof... (_UElements)), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_ImplicitlyMoveConvertibleTuple<_UElements ...>()) && (5ul >= 1)), bool>::type <anonymous> > constexpr std::tuple< <template-parameter-1-1> >::tuple(_UElements&& ...) [with _UElements = {const std::tuple<void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>&}; typename std::enable_if<(((std::_TC<(sizeof... (_UElements) == 1), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_NotSameTuple<_UElements ...>() && std::_TC<(1ul == sizeof... (_UElements)), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_MoveConstructibleTuple<_UElements ...>()) && std::_TC<(1ul == sizeof... (_UElements)), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_ImplicitlyMoveConvertibleTuple<_UElements ...>()) && (5ul >= 1)), bool>::type <anonymous> = <missing>]'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/functional:1363:8:   required from 'struct std::_Bind_simple<void (*(int, camera*, int*, int*))(int, camera*, int*, int*)>'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/thread:136:55:   required from 'std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*); _Args = {int&, camera*, int*&, int*&}]'
/...snip.../ofunctions.hpp:3221:97:   required from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/tuple:483:67: error: mismatched argument pack lengths while expanding 'std::is_constructible<_Elements, _UElements&&>'
       return __and_<is_constructible<_Elements, _UElements&&>...>::value;
                                                                   ^~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/tuple:484:1: error: body of constexpr function 'static constexpr bool std::_TC<<anonymous>, _Elements>::_MoveConstructibleTuple() [with _UElements = {const std::tuple<void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>&}; bool <anonymous> = true; _Elements = {void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*}]' not a return-statement
     }
 ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/tuple: In instantiation of 'static constexpr bool std::_TC<<anonymous>, _Elements>::_ImplicitlyMoveConvertibleTuple() [with _UElements = {const std::tuple<void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>&}; bool <anonymous> = true; _Elements = {void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*}]':
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/tuple:626:362:   required by substitution of 'template<class ... _UElements, typename std::enable_if<(((std::_TC<(sizeof... (_UElements) == 1), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_NotSameTuple<_UElements ...>() && std::_TC<(1ul == sizeof... (_UElements)), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_MoveConstructibleTuple<_UElements ...>()) && std::_TC<(1ul == sizeof... (_UElements)), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_ImplicitlyMoveConvertibleTuple<_UElements ...>()) && (5ul >= 1)), bool>::type <anonymous> > constexpr std::tuple< <template-parameter-1-1> >::tuple(_UElements&& ...) [with _UElements = {const std::tuple<void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>&}; typename std::enable_if<(((std::_TC<(sizeof... (_UElements) == 1), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_NotSameTuple<_UElements ...>() && std::_TC<(1ul == sizeof... (_UElements)), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_MoveConstructibleTuple<_UElements ...>()) && std::_TC<(1ul == sizeof... (_UElements)), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_ImplicitlyMoveConvertibleTuple<_UElements ...>()) && (5ul >= 1)), bool>::type <anonymous> = <missing>]'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/functional:1363:8:   required from 'struct std::_Bind_simple<void (*(int, camera*, int*, int*))(int, camera*, int*, int*)>'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/thread:136:55:   required from 'std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*); _Args = {int&, camera*, int*&, int*&}]'
/...snip.../ofunctions.hpp:3221:97:   required from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/tuple:489:65: error: mismatched argument pack lengths while expanding 'std::is_convertible<_UElements&&, _Elements>'
       return __and_<is_convertible<_UElements&&, _Elements>...>::value;
                                                                 ^~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/tuple:490:1: error: body of constexpr function 'static constexpr bool std::_TC<<anonymous>, _Elements>::_ImplicitlyMoveConvertibleTuple() [with _UElements = {const std::tuple<void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>&}; bool <anonymous> = true; _Elements = {void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*}]' not a return-statement
     }
 ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/tuple: In instantiation of 'static constexpr bool std::_TC<<anonymous>, _Elements>::_NonNestedTuple() [with _SrcTuple = const std::tuple<void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>&; bool <anonymous> = true; _Elements = {void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*}]':
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/tuple:662:419:   required by substitution of 'template<class ... _UElements, class _Dummy, typename std::enable_if<((std::_TC<(1ul == sizeof... (_UElements)), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_ConstructibleTuple<_UElements ...>() && std::_TC<(1ul == sizeof... (_UElements)), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_ImplicitlyConvertibleTuple<_UElements ...>()) && std::_TC<(std::is_same<_Dummy, void>::value && (1ul == 1)), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_NonNestedTuple<const tuple<_Elements ...>&>()), bool>::type <anonymous> > constexpr std::tuple< <template-parameter-1-1> >::tuple(const std::tuple<_Args1 ...>&) [with _UElements = {void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*}; _Dummy = void; typename std::enable_if<((std::_TC<(1ul == sizeof... (_UElements)), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_ConstructibleTuple<_UElements ...>() && std::_TC<(1ul == sizeof... (_UElements)), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_ImplicitlyConvertibleTuple<_UElements ...>()) && std::_TC<(std::is_same<_Dummy, void>::value && (1ul == 1)), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_NonNestedTuple<const tuple<_Elements ...>&>()), bool>::type <anonymous> = <missing>]'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/functional:1363:8:   required from 'struct std::_Bind_simple<void (*(int, camera*, int*, int*))(int, camera*, int*, int*)>'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/thread:136:55:   required from 'std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*); _Args = {int&, camera*, int*&, int*&}]'
/...snip.../ofunctions.hpp:3221:97:   required from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/tuple:495:244: error: wrong number of template arguments (6, should be 2)
       return  __and_<__not_<is_same<tuple<_Elements...>,
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ^    
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/type_traits:1558:8: note: provided for 'template<class _From, class _To> struct std::is_convertible'
     struct is_convertible
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/tuple:502:1: error: body of constexpr function 'static constexpr bool std::_TC<<anonymous>, _Elements>::_NonNestedTuple() [with _SrcTuple = const std::tuple<void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>&; bool <anonymous> = true; _Elements = {void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*}]' not a return-statement
     }
 ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/tuple: In instantiation of 'static constexpr bool std::_TC<<anonymous>, _Elements>::_MoveConstructibleTuple() [with _UElements = {std::tuple<void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>}; bool <anonymous> = true; _Elements = {void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*}]':
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/tuple:626:248:   required by substitution of 'template<class ... _UElements, typename std::enable_if<(((std::_TC<(sizeof... (_UElements) == 1), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_NotSameTuple<_UElements ...>() && std::_TC<(1ul == sizeof... (_UElements)), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_MoveConstructibleTuple<_UElements ...>()) && std::_TC<(1ul == sizeof... (_UElements)), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_ImplicitlyMoveConvertibleTuple<_UElements ...>()) && (5ul >= 1)), bool>::type <anonymous> > constexpr std::tuple< <template-parameter-1-1> >::tuple(_UElements&& ...) [with _UElements = {std::tuple<void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>}; typename std::enable_if<(((std::_TC<(sizeof... (_UElements) == 1), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_NotSameTuple<_UElements ...>() && std::_TC<(1ul == sizeof... (_UElements)), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_MoveConstructibleTuple<_UElements ...>()) && std::_TC<(1ul == sizeof... (_UElements)), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_ImplicitlyMoveConvertibleTuple<_UElements ...>()) && (5ul >= 1)), bool>::type <anonymous> = <missing>]'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/functional:1363:8:   required from 'struct std::_Bind_simple<void (*(int, camera*, int*, int*))(int, camera*, int*, int*)>'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/thread:136:55:   required from 'std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*); _Args = {int&, camera*, int*&, int*&}]'
/...snip.../ofunctions.hpp:3221:97:   required from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/tuple:483:67: error: mismatched argument pack lengths while expanding 'std::is_constructible<_Elements, _UElements&&>'
       return __and_<is_constructible<_Elements, _UElements&&>...>::value;
                                                                   ^~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/tuple:484:1: error: body of constexpr function 'static constexpr bool std::_TC<<anonymous>, _Elements>::_MoveConstructibleTuple() [with _UElements = {std::tuple<void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>}; bool <anonymous> = true; _Elements = {void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*}]' not a return-statement
     }
 ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/tuple: In instantiation of 'static constexpr bool std::_TC<<anonymous>, _Elements>::_ImplicitlyMoveConvertibleTuple() [with _UElements = {std::tuple<void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>}; bool <anonymous> = true; _Elements = {void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*}]':
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/tuple:626:362:   required by substitution of 'template<class ... _UElements, typename std::enable_if<(((std::_TC<(sizeof... (_UElements) == 1), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_NotSameTuple<_UElements ...>() && std::_TC<(1ul == sizeof... (_UElements)), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_MoveConstructibleTuple<_UElements ...>()) && std::_TC<(1ul == sizeof... (_UElements)), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_ImplicitlyMoveConvertibleTuple<_UElements ...>()) && (5ul >= 1)), bool>::type <anonymous> > constexpr std::tuple< <template-parameter-1-1> >::tuple(_UElements&& ...) [with _UElements = {std::tuple<void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>}; typename std::enable_if<(((std::_TC<(sizeof... (_UElements) == 1), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_NotSameTuple<_UElements ...>() && std::_TC<(1ul == sizeof... (_UElements)), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_MoveConstructibleTuple<_UElements ...>()) && std::_TC<(1ul == sizeof... (_UElements)), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_ImplicitlyMoveConvertibleTuple<_UElements ...>()) && (5ul >= 1)), bool>::type <anonymous> = <missing>]'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/functional:1363:8:   required from 'struct std::_Bind_simple<void (*(int, camera*, int*, int*))(int, camera*, int*, int*)>'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/thread:136:55:   required from 'std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*); _Args = {int&, camera*, int*&, int*&}]'
/...snip.../ofunctions.hpp:3221:97:   required from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/tuple:489:65: error: mismatched argument pack lengths while expanding 'std::is_convertible<_UElements&&, _Elements>'
       return __and_<is_convertible<_UElements&&, _Elements>...>::value;
                                                                 ^~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/tuple:490:1: error: body of constexpr function 'static constexpr bool std::_TC<<anonymous>, _Elements>::_ImplicitlyMoveConvertibleTuple() [with _UElements = {std::tuple<void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>}; bool <anonymous> = true; _Elements = {void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*}]' not a return-statement
     }
 ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/tuple: In instantiation of 'static constexpr bool std::_TC<<anonymous>, _Elements>::_NonNestedTuple() [with _SrcTuple = std::tuple<void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>&&; bool <anonymous> = true; _Elements = {void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*}]':
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/tuple:686:422:   required by substitution of 'template<class ... _UElements, class _Dummy, typename std::enable_if<((std::_TC<(1ul == sizeof... (_UElements)), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_MoveConstructibleTuple<_UElements ...>() && std::_TC<(1ul == sizeof... (_UElements)), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_ImplicitlyMoveConvertibleTuple<_UElements ...>()) && std::_TC<(std::is_same<_Dummy, void>::value && (1ul == 1)), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_NonNestedTuple<tuple<_Elements ...>&&>()), bool>::type <anonymous> > constexpr std::tuple< <template-parameter-1-1> >::tuple(std::tuple<_Args1 ...>&&) [with _UElements = {void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*}; _Dummy = void; typename std::enable_if<((std::_TC<(1ul == sizeof... (_UElements)), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_MoveConstructibleTuple<_UElements ...>() && std::_TC<(1ul == sizeof... (_UElements)), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_ImplicitlyMoveConvertibleTuple<_UElements ...>()) && std::_TC<(std::is_same<_Dummy, void>::value && (1ul == 1)), void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>::_NonNestedTuple<tuple<_Elements ...>&&>()), bool>::type <anonymous> = <missing>]'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/functional:1363:8:   required from 'struct std::_Bind_simple<void (*(int, camera*, int*, int*))(int, camera*, int*, int*)>'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/thread:136:55:   required from 'std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*); _Args = {int&, camera*, int*&, int*&}]'
/...snip.../ofunctions.hpp:3221:97:   required from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/tuple:495:244: error: wrong number of template arguments (6, should be 2)
       return  __and_<__not_<is_same<tuple<_Elements...>,
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ^    
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/type_traits:1558:8: note: provided for 'template<class _From, class _To> struct std::is_convertible'
     struct is_convertible
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include/g++-v6/tuple:502:1: error: body of constexpr function 'static constexpr bool std::_TC<<anonymous>, _Elements>::_NonNestedTuple() [with _SrcTuple = std::tuple<void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*>&&; bool <anonymous> = true; _Elements = {void (*)(int, camera*, int*, int*), int, camera*, int*, int*}]' not a return-statement
     }
 ^
CMake Error at ocapture_generated_ocapture.cu.o.cmake:282 (message):
  Error generating file
  /...snip.../build/CMakeFiles/ocapture.dir//./ocapture_generated_ocapture.cu.o


make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ocapture.dir/build.make:510: CMakeFiles/ocapture.dir/ocapture_generated_ocapture.cu.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: CMakeFiles/ocapture.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

Comment: C++ had tuples since 2011. But the most likely explanation is using `std::ref` to pass a non-lvalue to a thread function. What exactly do you expect to accomplish by using `std::ref` to pass a parameter to a new thread method that takes a plain, native pointer as a parameter. And since this pointer, from the looks of it, appears to be a class member, why do you need to explicitly pass it to the class method in the first place?

Comment: Thanks. I changed the code: prototype windowRender(void), and stopped passing the member function with std::ref().

See original post for new errors...

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong from the shown fragments, so without a [mcve], that anyone can try compiling on their own, it's unlikely that anything further can be suggested.

Comment: Thanks Sam. I created an example but it compiles and runs for both gcc 5.4 and gcc 6.3. The significant difference between the two codes is that I'm using CUDA as the compiler, so I'm beginning to suspect that the issue is CUDA. I'll change the example to a cuda .cu file and see if it compiles... If it doesn't compile with 6.3 and cuda 9, I'll file a bug with NVIDIA.

Comment: Update: The error messages shown above do not refer to the original issue which appears to have been cleared up by removing the std:ref because the pointer it was passing was not needed. The above error is related to another std:thread call in another file which I'm investigating now.

Answer (score 1):

I've had your exact same issue for a couple of days and when I read your conclusions on "threads" I managed to create a test project which fails in GCC 6.1.0 but works on 5.3.0.

It's important to note it fails **when compiled under CUDA**, that is, the Launcher is a .cu file. If you compile it as a .cpp file the problem will be gone by setting the -pthread flag in the compiling process.

I am now working with 5.3.0 because of this. I'm attaching here the code which fails. The software used to make it fail:

CMake 10, Ninja, GCC 6.3.0, CUDA 9.0.176

Launcher:

```
#include "ClassWithT/Functions.hpp"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    int* m = (int*)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    float* n = (float*)malloc(2 * sizeof(float));
    m[0] = 5;
    m[1] = 6;
    n[0] = 2.5f;
    n[1] = 5.6f;
    Functions<int>* f = new Functions<int>(m, 2, 0);
    std::cout << f->ManagingFutures() << std::endl;

    Functions<float>* g = new Functions<float>(n, 2, 0);
    std::cout << g->ManagingFutures() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Functions.ipp:

```
#pragma once
#include "Functions.hpp"

template<class T>
Functions<T>::Functions(T* list, int numValues, bool type)
{
    valuesList = list;
    numberOfValuesInList = numValues;
    typeOfOperation = type;
}

template<class T>
T Functions<T>::DoSomeStuff()
{

    T intAmount;
    if (typeOfOperation == 0)
    {
        intAmount = valuesList[0] + valuesList[1];
    }
    else
    {
        intAmount = valuesList[0] - valuesList[1];
    }
    return intAmount;
}

template<class T>
T Functions<T>::ManagingFutures()
{
    std::future<T> testThread;
    testThread = std::async(std::launch::async, &Functions::DoSomeStuff, this);
    return testThread.get();
}
```

Functions.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#ifndef FUNCTIONS_HPP
#define FUNCTIONS_HPP
#include <future>
template<class T>
class Functions
{
public:

    Functions(T* intList, int numIntegers, bool type);
    T DoSomeStuff();
    T ManagingFutures();
private:

    T* valuesList;
    int numberOfValuesInList;
    bool typeOfOperation;

};

#include "Functions.ipp"

#endif
```

I don't get why it fails yet. May I issue a bug to Nvidia or GCC?

May you want to reproduce it and get any troubles, feel free to comment, I will help you out!

Best regards guys!

Comment: Just saw this message. Did you open a case with Nvidia? If you send them this code they will debug it. I'm still having this problem with gcc 6.4 and cuda 9.0. gcc 5.4 works fine. I'm going to open a case with nvidia with your code, hope you don't mind. Strike that, I'll try cuda 9.1 first, then file a bug report.

Comment: Hi! Yes, I opened a bug case to Nvidia. If you try with 9.1 keep me posted just to update the bug case with that information. I know they have been checking the bug report regularly but no news yet.

Comment: I'll work on a 9.1 ebuild as soon as I can. I got distracted this weekend.

Comment: It seems they are working already on it, as the bug case has changed the status:  "Status changed from "Open - pending review" to "Open - Fix being tested" "

Comment: I just check 9.1 and it fails exactly the same way. Thanks for checking the bug and posting back here.